# Fill fields in opened browser in Android app

Tags: android, browser, autofill

I am looking for an answer on this problem.

Is there a way to fill fields on particular link, but not via webView? Instead of webView I am using device's default browser as shown:

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
```

Any examples or solutions would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.
You can't control the external browser and the code you provided starts an external application.

Comment: Thank you, so do you suggest to just make it with webView?

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, I think you should make it with `WebView` :)